# Javascript curly bracket operator with constant value

Tags: javascript

This is purely a javascript trivia question. When i open my console and type in:

```
{"a"}
```

This evaluates to `"a"`. What does the curly brackets mean in this case? It can't be destructuring because there's no assignment, and because the thing inside the curly brackets is a constant string value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a plain block - like the block of a for loop, only without the loop.

```
for (let i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
  "a"
}
```

The block also "evaluates" to "a", the final expression in it, which is why it gets logged by the console.

(This sort of [statement completion value](https://www.mattzeunert.com/2017/01/10/whats-a-statement-completion-value-in-javascript.html#:%7E:text=Intuitvely%2C%20a%20statement%20completion%20value,t%20just%20plain%20JavaScript%20values.) of a *block*, as opposed to an expression, is pretty much never seen or used in JavaScript - except when typing stuff into the console like this.)

A block

```
{
  // some code
  // NOT containing object literal syntax
}
```

is a bit like a `for` loop with a single iteration, and a bit like [an IIFE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript) - a segment of code with its own scope. But it's weird and confusing - best not to use plain blocks in real code.

Comment: Neat! In fact I do have a use case for it hahaha (and yeah i know its bad practice) - when I'm working on a codebase that could be split into multiple files but i dont want to (because webpack doesn't like my purejs and load time), I would use `(()=>{code})()` to scope chunks of code so my `let` statements are scoped. Bonus points for the IDE collapsing option for code surrounded by `{}`. Just using `{code}` instead of `(()=>{code})()` is so much nicer!